# Passing different values to the same directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have one chart directive where i create a Morris.js graph. I put this directive 5 times on my site.

I have one controller which is handling all the different data.

> How can i achieve to make my directive generic enough to handle different data?

*I put everything in the same scope.*

1. My approach is to use the data-attribute:

So i can decide on the data-attribute which data i should use.

```
<div id="chart" data="income" barchart></div>
```

My Directive looks like this:

```
  angular.module('app')
  .directive('donutchart', function () {
    return {
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        if(attrs.data === "income") var data = scope.income_data;
        new Morris.Donut({element: element[0].id, data: data});
      }
    };
  });
```

But what would be a good approach handling over different data to the same directive and staying very generic? **I want to take the data-attribute as a variable-name though, but still, its not "clean".**

Comment: How do you want your scope to be structured in order to handle your data?

Comment: like this: scope.country_name : { income: [ { label: '2008', value: 20 }, label: '2009', value: 25 ], age: [ { ... } ] }

Comment: And you want to call the directive like this: <div id="chart" data="income" barchart></div> and <div id="chart" data="age" barchart></div> and so on?

Comment: yes. The id can change, i don't mind this. <div id="chart_01" data="income" barchart></div> and <div id="chart_02" data="age" barchart></div> This is what i mean. With the id i'm totally generic because i take it from element[0].id. Also the data-attribute was a suggestion because this is the only thing i can think of to identify the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can write something like this

```
app.directive('donutchart', function () {
  return {
    scope: {
      mymodel: "=data",
      id: "@"
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      new Morris.Donut({element: scope.id, data: scope.mymodel});
    }
  };
});
```

The id: "@" declaration in the isolated scope means that you want the value as a string and not an expression,

Comment: You are right, I missed that one. I've corrected it now.

Answer (score 1):

you have to add this in your directive

```
scope: {
    id: '=id',
    data: '=data',
  },
```

if you want to use it in your link, its though attrs exemple : attrs.id

Comment: I don't get this at all... i don't want to create a new scope!

Comment: you have 2 choices, or pass by this scope, or pass by attrs in link  link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
     attrs.data;
           

                

            });

        }